# What's the name of the table used to determine test vectors?

Tags: circuit-design

I'm reading fault model section in the book: `VLSI Test Principles and Architectures: Design for Testability`, page 23, and came across following figure.
[image: img]

What's the name/method of the table present here? There's limited explanation presented there.

Comment: Isn't that the first lesson in digital design? K-maps and truth tables course ...

Comment: Those illustrations are Karnaugh maps, but test vectors would normally come from truth tables.